# How to instantiate List<T> but T is unknown until runtime?

Tags: c#

Assume I have a class that is unknown until runtime.
At runtime I get a reference, x, of type Type referencing to Foo.GetType().
Only by using x and List<>, can I create a list of type Foo?

How to do that?

Comment: Anything stopping you simply creating a `List<object>`?

Comment: @Flynn1179, let me see how you do that please.

Comment: `List<object> myList = new List<object>();`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Type x = typeof(Foo);
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(x);
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Of course you shouldn't expect any type safety here as the resulting list is of type `object` at compile time. Using `List<object>` would be more practical but still limited type safety because the type of `Foo` is known only at runtime.

Comment: Nice! Your answer also suggests (correctly) that working with such a list will be quite type-unsafe. One could, of course, declare `list` as being of a (non-generic) type `IList` or `ICollection` (instead of just `object`), accompanied by a corresponding cast of `Activator.CreateInstance`'s return value, so that a limited way of working with `list` as a collection becomes possible.

Comment: If you create types at runtime, sure there can not be any compile-time type safety.

Answer (score 11):

Sure you can:

```
var fooList = Activator
    .CreateInstance(typeof(List<>)
    .MakeGenericType(Foo.GetType()));
```

The Problem here is that `fooList` is of type `object` so you still would have to cast it to a "usable" type. But what would this type look like? As a data structure supporting adding and looking up objects of type `T` `List<T>` (or rather `IList<>`) is not covariant in `T` so you cannot cast a `List<Foo>` to a `List<IFoo>` where `Foo: IFoo`. You could cast it to an `IEnumerable<T>` which is covariant in `T`.

If you are using C# 4.0 you could also consider casting `fooList` to `dynamic` so you can at least use it as a list (e.g. add, look-up and remove objects).

Considering all this and the fact, that you don't have any compile-time type safety when creating types at runtime anyhow, simply using a `List<object>` is probably the best/most pragmatic way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type))

Answer (score -1):

Given a type, you can instantiate a new instance this way:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: And then, how to instatiate List<Foo> ?