# Instantiate a generic list from object

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code

```
    public void MyMethod(object myClass)
    {
       if(myClass.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyBaseClass)))
       {
          // Instantiate a generic list here....
          // Assume that myClass is type Class1, e.g. List<Class1> abc = new List<Class1>();
       }
    }
```

Within the if statement I want to create a List of the type of myClass. Is this possible? I am assuming it is through reflection but I can't see how to do it.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888375/how-to-instatiate-listt-but-t-is-unknown-until-runtime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { myClass.GetType() });
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
```