# Creating List with non-knowing type

Tags: c#

Why in C# I can not write

```
MyClass m = new MyClass(2,3);
Type T = m.GetType();
List<T> ll = new List<T>();
```

or something like

```
MyClass m = new MyClass(2,3);
Type T = typeof(m);
List<T> ll = new List<T>();
```

??

Is it possible to change this code and write anything similar??

Comment: [A generic list of anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)

Comment: because your code doesn't make sense. What would you do with `ll` if you don't know the type of object it stores? What would you expect from Intellisense, for example? and Since the type of `T` is resolved at runtime as opposed to compile time, there's no way to guarantee type safety. Your approach is really odd.

Comment: Have you tried my code? It's exactly what you're asking for...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it impossible to use Generics dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234008/is-it-impossible-to-use-generics-dynamically)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generically instantiate a generic class in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716306/how-to-generically-instantiate-a-generic-class-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Although generics are resolved at run time, the compiler provides safety checks. It thus requires you to specify the class name and not an instance of Type when typing statements like `List<MyClass>...=`

ie specify the type instead of passing a Type instance.

If you wish to have a generic that is resolved at execution time you would have to use reflection.
See 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Type x = typeof(Foo);
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(x);
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

You could cast the `Activator`'s result as `IList` to have access to its methods.

```
var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Of course you shouldn't expect any type safety here as the resulting list is of type object at compile time. Using List would be more practical but still limited type safety because the type of Foo is known only at runtime.

You could also read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888375/how-to-instatiate-listt-but-t-is-unknown-until-runtime)